# Из-за чего ошибка и как исправить?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import PhotoImage

root=Tk()
root.geometry('141x124')
root.resizable(0, 0)

our_image= PhotoImage(file= "1.png")
our_label= Label(root)
our_label.image=our_image
our_label['image']=our_label.image
our_label.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\program\summer\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    our_image= PhotoImage(file= "1.png")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4130, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4075, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "1.png"
```

Comment: PhotoImage из tkinter не поддерживает png. Используйте PIL / Pillow